# Mapping fields under @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I would like to newer have nulls for my fields which are type of "list"

As I understead below are points where object are initializated, so in these we should do something to initializate empty list in case of null.

- Controller (When object is comming from frontend)
- Initialization (new AnyObject() or AnyObject.toBuilder - lombok)
- FeginClient - Calls between Apis

Is there some framework/annotation which in case of null will set empty list?

Below is what I have currently done

```
public class TestMapin {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Test test = new Test();

        notNull(test);

        System.out.println(test);
    }

    public static void notNull(Object test) throws IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : test.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

            boolean access = field.canAccess(test);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.get(test) == null) {
                if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
                    field.set(test, Collections.emptyList());
                } else if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Map.class)) {
                    field.set(test, Collections.emptyMap());
                }
            } else if (field.getType().getPackageName().contains("org.owozniak.selfestem")) {
                notNull(field);
            }

            field.setAccessible(access);
        }
    }
}

@Setter
@ToString
class Test {
    private ArrayList<String> stringList;
    private Box box = Box.builder().build();
    private Magazine magazine;
}
```

So, I need to use 
- initializating via toBuilder - @Singular annotation
- Controllers/Feign clients - inject this code snippet to spring filters
- Initialization via constructor - Use static factory method which will use this code snipped and return "enchanced" instance

Any more ideas/frameworks?

Comment: Not able to understand your doubt at all can you please explain more?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. If you want an empty list by default then can't you just do `List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: This won't work if I would receive this instance in controller

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use @Singular annotation along with @Builder. This will initialize collection with a non-null List. By annotating one of the parameters (if annotating a method or constructor with @Builder) or fields (if annotating a class with @Builder) with the @Singular annotation, lombok will treat that builder node as a collection, and it generates 2 ‘adder’ methods instead of a ‘setter’ method. One which adds a single element to the collection, and one which adds all elements of another collection to the collection. No setter to just set the collection (replacing whatever was already added) will be generated. A ‘clear’ method is also generated. You can read full details on my recent article https://technicalsand.com/using-lombok-advanced-features/

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Singular;
import java.util.Set;
@Builder
public class BuilderExample {
    @Builder.Default private long created = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @Singular 
    private Set<String> occupations;
}
```

Comment: This will help in field initialization what about when payload with list which is null is comming as null from frontend?